# Make grails service method atomic in multi-user environment

Tags: java, grails, parallel-processing, atomic

I have a grails service method, load, that I only want one user at a time to be able to run.  I have tried using Grails pessimistic lock but it only sometimes works.  In my controller, I have:

```
try {
    def country = Country.lock(id)
    myService.load(country)
} catch (CannotAcquireLockException ex) {
    flash.message = "Another user is modifying ${Country.get(id)}"
}
```

What is the best way to make load method of myService atomic?

What if I want two methods to be atomic (When one is executing, neither can execute)?

My service's method:

```
def load(id) {
    def country = Country.get(id)
    country.states.each {
        ...
        it.save(flush: true)
    }
}
```

Adding the synchronized keyword to this method causes a StaleObjectStateException on the save.

Answer (score 2):

Grails services are singletons by default which takes care of part of your problem.  You should also make your service method synchronized to achieve what you want:

```
def synchronized load(country) { ... }
```

Comment: When I add the synchronized keyword, I get a StaleObjectStateException when I save.  I've edited my post to show a little more detail of my load method.

Comment: From the following documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html, I am interpreting that the synchronize keyword on two methods of the same class will prevent either from being run when one is already running.  Is that correct?

Comment: +1 for the tip, it helped me identify that java's ReentrantLock is what I should use.  I am still curious why synchronized threw that exception.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@synchronized` annotation with a custom synchronization lock. This way you won't be synchronizing `this` (whole service class), only the given method.

Code sample

```
class MyCustomService

private final myLock = new Object()

@Synchronized("myLock")
def myRunOneAtATimeMethod(int x, int y)
    return x+y
```

More about synchronization: http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/Synchronized.html

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved as an ordinary Java synchronization problem using [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html).  I can use isLocked to return an error instead of making user wait for the lock to do the same thing.